# what is a library exerciser program?

Tags: unix, terminology

I was reading "The Art of Unix Programming" book and I found a quote saying :

> **In the Unix world, libraries which are delivered as libraries should come with exerciser programs.**

So what exactly is a library exerciser?

Comment: Since the question does not bear any source code, shouldn't it be asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead of here?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: IMHO, there should be an easy way to migrate a question to programmers. (e.g. Close => Off-topic => Migrate to programmers)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it's been there in the past. [Was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134642/165773) after it turned out that too many of SO folks abused it to dump garbage off their site. See [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: Well, my criteria (both for asking questions & giving answers) is: question with (possible) source code: yes => on Stack Overflow, no => on Programmers...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch consider adjusting the criteria in accordance with their meta FAQ: [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library exerciser is simply a program, or a collection of programs, that is testing that library (by calling some, or most, and ideally all public functions or methods of that library). Read also about [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

BTW, this advice to make library exercisers is IMHO not specific to the Unix world (it should also hold for GNU Hurd, POSIX, VMS and even Windows systems), but generally useful for any software [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29). I guess it is related to [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) and names in [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29). In some exotic, but interesting, programming environments (think of Lisp or Smalltalk machines, or persistent academic OSes like [Grasshopper](http://www-systems.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/gh/)) the very notion of library does not exist, or is so far from Linux-like libraries (written in C or C++) that exercisers might not mean the same thing... ....

Notice that some languages (Ocaml, Go, D, ... but not C11 or C++14) might know some notion of modules and have a module-aware notion of libraries